English /j/ "mutation" in certain contexts
First of all, I cannot provide any actual audio data, but I am fairly certain that I have heard this phenomenon before.
In American English, in a dialect, there appears to be a [j] insertion (or [r] to [j] mutation). For example, I have heard heart pronounced as [hɑjt] instead of [hɑrt], of course as [ʌvkɔjs] instead of [ʌvkɔrs], and ever as [evəj] instead of [evər]. Although, I am not entirely sure about the last one, i.e. if this is attested word-finally.
So, in some contexts a [j] is pronounced after a vowel (VrC --> VjC). I would guess that after the open vowels and schwa maybe.
Could it be that such a phenomenon exists and I heard it right? If so, could someone explain this phenomenon or provide more examples and contexts where it occurs?
Thanks!

Off the top of my head, I associate this with a really strong New York accent ("birds" being "boids" /bojdz/ and such), but I don't think it's as prominent now as it used to be.

As @Draconis says, this is especially associated with New York, but it’s attested elsewhere as well. It’s often called upgliding NURSE (because it results in the NURSE vowel becoming a diphthong that glides upwards, from /ə/ or /ɔ/ to /ɪ/). These days it’s more of a well-known trope (the famous phrase for it is Toidy-Toid street for Thirty-Third Street) than an actual dialect feature; it’s been on the way out for a long time.

@JanusBahsJacquet That would make a good answer!

I believe it would not happen word-finally.

Thank you, everyone! This helped me a lot.
I actually found a rabbit hole with this.
The case is that most of the speakers use the rhotic form with NURSE but they produce non-rhotic forms with, say, forth.
It turns out that some younger speakers still use both rhotic and non-rhotic varieties of NURSE, and when they hesitate, they use the upglide form [əɪ] or [ɜɪ].
Do we maybe know why this oi emerged? Could this be an impact of, say, Italian or Yiddish-speaking immigrants of the time?
